# Mapping large string with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm working with an Oracle DB, and I'm trying to map this class:

```
public class Book
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Author { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

With this mapping class:

```
public class BookMap : ClassMap<Book>
{
    public BookMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Author);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.Text);
    }
}
```

But the column type that it generates me is NVARCHAR(255), And the `Book.Text` Property has much more than 255 characters.

How can I map it to a type that can contain a very large string (for example CLOB)?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343105/override-for-fluent-nhibernate-for-long-text-strings-nvarcharmax-not-nvarchar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public class BookMap : ClassMap<Book>
{
    public BookMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Author);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.Text).CustomSqlType("CLOB");
    }
}
```

or

```
public class BookMap : ClassMap<Book>
{
    public BookMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Author);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.Text).Length(500);  // nvarchar(500)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `CustomType("StringClob")` ?

Comment: @ChrisS. StringClob is for SQL Server, the question was about Oracle

Comment: After being mislead by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8737680/734181). I got what I needed here. Thanks @TimHoolihan