# Mapping large string with Fluent NHibernate 2

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, clob

my code:

```
public SendOrderMap()
{
    Table("Sendorder");
    Id(s => s.ID).GeneratedBy.Sequence("SEQ_SendOrder");
    Map(s => s.YBID);
    Map(s => s.TITLE);
    Map(s => s.MESSAGE).CustomSqlType("NCLOB").CustomType("StringClob");
}
```

when it dependent FluentNHibernate 1.3 + NHibernate4.0,it is OK!

but now I use FluentNHibernate 2.0.3 + NHibernate4.1.1,it is wrong! error tip:

> ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
>   tips

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long strings in N-Hibernate with Oracle cause error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737680/long-strings-in-n-hibernate-with-oracle-cause-error)

Comment: This behavior of trying to mistakenly use `LONG` for upating a `CLOB` or `NCLOB` is a known bug of the Oracle managed driver, having workarounds as written in above linked question answer. If you think your case is different, please provide more information, such as which lines of code trigger the error, which Oracle dialect and driver are in use, ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the almost exactly the same problem.
My field was mapped like this:

```
Map(Function(x) x.Remark, "REMARK").Length(4000)
```

And when inserting values for this Remark string that were longer than 1000 characters, I got the same error as the original poster:

```
"ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column"
```

I solved it very easily:

- Updated NHibernate to v4.1.1.4000
- Updated Fluent NHibernate to v2.0.3
- Updated Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to v12.1.24160719

It looks like Oracle has fixed the known bug in the Managed driver!