# How to store a non truncated varchar(max) string with NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

My DB schema has a string as a varchar(max). I have read the other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343105/override-for-fluent-nhibernate-for-long-text-strings-nvarcharmax-not-nvarchar2) concerning setting Length to more than 4000 or 8000 so that it really generates a (n)varchar(max) in the mapping but when I use Length(10000) in my mapping class, the hbm file actually shows length="10000" and if I save an entity with more than 10000 chars, it is actually truncated to exactly 10000 chars.

I don't want any truncation.

(using NH3-alpha2 and FNH trunk)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It would appear that this is an old problem which is now resurfacing in NHibernate 3.x builds; you can read about the workarounds [here](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-prepare_sql-considerations-mapping-long-string-fields).

```
<property name="Blob" column="Blob" type="StringClob" />
<!-- this generates an nvarchar(max), data is truncated at the length specified: string(10000) -->
<property name="BlobLength" column="BlobLength" type="StringClob" length="10000" />
<!-- this mapping works! for generation, reading and writing -->
<property name="BlobSqlType" type="StringClob" >
    <column name="BlobSqlType" sql-type="nvarchar(max)" />
</property>
```

Calling `CustomType("StringClob")` should fix the problem.

**Note**: I have updated the original link I posted as it was outdated.

Comment: In an hbm mapping file, simply use type="StringClob" instead of type="string" and you're done. This definitely works for NH 3.3, but try it with for any NH version >= 3.0.

Comment: Note that StringClob will generate a nvchar(255) on SQL Server 2008, and instead the workaround is to use a .Length(10000). This will create a nvchar(max) column type.

Answer (score 17):

This mapping should work:

```
<property name="TheProperty" type="StringClob">
  <column name="TheColumn" sql-type="nvarchar(max)" />
</property>
```

Just look for the fluent equivalent.

Comment: do you think this will ever be treated properly in NHib 3? Kind of sad to see the sql server specific details leak through in the mapping like this...

Comment: I believe there already is one: http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2302 Incidentally...would you be interested in a donated domain name for the JIRA or something? Having an IP based url seems a little...inconvenient ;)

Comment: @DanP, the domain name is jira.nhforge.org, I have no clue why it's being using the IP for some months now. I don't administer it, but you can ask in the dev list.

Comment: The fluent equivalent is `.CustomType("StringClob").CustomSqlType("nvarchar(max)")`

Comment: what if you wanted to go against something other than sql server?  No way to set the length of the field to -1 or something and let the dialect engine sort it out?

Comment: Nope, only fixed in not yet released v4.1. See [NH-3252](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3252). (Founded at the end of [this answer](/a/12106405/1178314) to the same issue with hbm mapping.