# Can't insert long string to database table in Orchard

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, orchardcms

I created table

```
    private static void CreateTable(SchemaBuilder builder) {
        builder.CreateTable(typeof(RkeeperV7MenuRecord).Name, table => table
            .Column<int>("Id", c => c.PrimaryKey().Identity())
            .Column<int>("SpotId", c => c.NotNull())
            .Column<DateTime>("Date", c => c.NotNull())
            .Column<string>("OriginalData", c => c.NotNull().Unlimited())
            );
```

and table in SQL Server database was created (and string has max in legth property). If i generate SQL table script from DB server it will be like this (so string is marked as unlimited)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Plus_Plus_SpotServerIntegration_Rkeeper_RkeeperV7MenuRecord](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SpotId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [OriginalData] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

But... When i try to insert record in table, nhibernate throw exception "Error dehydrating property value for Plus.SpotServerIntegration.Rkeeper.Models.RkeeperV7MenuRecord.OriginalData" and inner exception is "The length of the string value exceeds the length configured in the mapping/parameter."
What should i do to insert record?

**PS**
string is about 100000 simbols (it is xml)

```
            _rkeeperV7MenuRepositiory.Create(new RkeeperV7MenuRecord {
                OriginalData = model.OriginalData,
                SpotId = spot.Id,
                Date = _clock.UtcNow
            });
```

where

```
private readonly IRepository<RkeeperV7MenuRecord> _rkeeperV7MenuRepositiory;
```

Comment: How do you insert data into that table? bulk insert or only a single record?what is the biggest size of OriginalData field?

Comment: answer in question body (string is xml about 100000 simbols and insert operation code)

Comment: please take a look at this link, it may help. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/varcharmax-field-cutting-off-data-after-8000-characters-sql-server-2008

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store a non truncated varchar(max) string with NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701907/how-to-store-a-non-truncated-varcharmax-string-with-nhibernate-and-fluent-nhib)

Comment: Answer lies in first comment of [currently accepted answer](/a/3702382/1178314) of a same question: call `CustomType("StringClob")`.

Comment: String is NOT truncated. Just insert operation failed (throw an exception). And at the sql server, as i see, table structure and column attributes are correct ([OriginalData] [nvarchar](max)) I checked it. Yes, I know about CustomType("StringClob"), but... I am not sure if it help (operation insert, not table generate is failed) and Orchard CMS has huge wrapper over nhibernate, i think, there is buildin method in Orchard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!
Should mark Property record by attribute "StringLengthMax" like this

```
public class RkeeperV7MenuRecord : DefaultEntityRecord {
    public virtual int SpotId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [StringLengthMax]
    public virtual string OriginalData { get; set; }
}
```