# Fluent NHibernate's Length property not working on update

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have the next mapping, where I specify the length of some string fields:

```
public ResolutionMap()
{
  Schema("dbo");
  Table("Resolution");
  Id(x => x.IdResolution, "resolution_id").UnsavedValue(0).GeneratedBy.Identity();
  Component(x => x.Store, m =>
    {
      m.Map(y => y.StoreCodeId, "store_code_id");
      m.Map(y => y.StoreCode, "store_code").Length(10);
    }
  );
  Map(x => x.ResolutionData, "resolution_data").Length(42);
}
```

However, when I watch the update query executed at the SQL Server Profiler, I see that the length set on the mapping is not respected at all on the parameter declaration:

```
exec sp_executesql
  N'UPDATE dbo.Resolution SET resolution_data = @p0, store_code_id = @p1, store_code = @p2 WHERE resolution_id = @p3',
  N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 int,@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 int',
  @p0=N'Test',@p1=89,@p2=N'ST000003',@p3=275
```

Why could this be happening? I need to set the length because this slows the update process.

I am currently using Fluent NHibernate 1.3.0.733 and NHibernate 3.3.1 over .NET Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, `Length(x)` is only used if you are generating the database schema from the mappings.

NHibernate won't let you save a property to a column where truncation is involved, an exception will be raised.

`"String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated."`

What are the underlying types of the strings? Are the strings always the same length or do they vary? `varchar(x)` for example.

You can specify the lengths for example with:

`Map(x => x.StoreCode).CustomSqlType("varchar (512)");` etc.

Or can create a convention to set the default string length:

```
public class DefaultStringLengthConvention: IPropertyConvention
{
  public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
  {
    instance.Length(250);
  }
}
```

For more information, see:

[Override for fluent NHibernate for long text strings nvarchar(MAX) not nvarchar(255)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343105/override-for-fluent-nhibernate-for-long-text-strings-nvarcharmax-not-nvarchar)

http://marcinobel.com/index.php/fluent-nhibernate-conventions-examples/ - StringColumnLengthConvention

https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping

https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions